# Fluent Bit not saving any data on filesystem

Tags: linux, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am new to fluent bit and currently doing a POC. I tried multiple things but couldn't make Fluent Bit save any data to filesystem.

```
[SERVICE]
  flush        1
  daemon       Off
  log_level    trace
  parsers_file parsers.conf
  plugins_file plugins.conf
  http_server  on
  http_listen  0.0.0.0
  http_port    2020

  storage.metrics on
  storage.path /var/log/fluent-bit/buffer
  storage.max_chunks_up 4
  storage.sync full
  storage.backlog.mem_limit 1M

[INPUT]
  name cpu
  tag  cpu.local

  # Read interval (sec) Default: 1
  interval_sec 1

[INPUT]
  name          exec
  tag           d-disk
  command       df -h --type=ext4 | grep -v Filesystem
  interval_sec  1
  interval_nsec 0

[INPUT]
  name   mem
  tag    memory
  interval_sec 1


[OUTPUT]
  name  stdout
  match memory
```

When I go to /var/log/fluent-bit/buffer and run **ls -a** I see nothing.

My aim to make Fluent Bit save data on disk.

Comment: How are you running Fluent Bit? As a systemd service? In a Docker container? etc. What permissions does the user running Fluent Bit have on the filesystem path that you want to write logs to?

Comment: @JamesMishra - I run  "sudo service td-agent-bit start" command at "/etc/td-agent-bit" location.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You've got your `[OUTPUT]` configured to be `stdout`, so that's where you'd get the data, no? Did you have a look at https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/file already?

Answer (score 0):

Here we have to specifically mention the buffering mechanism to use. [more details](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/buffering-and-storage).

Try adding `storage.type filesystem` in your INPUT section